# PostgreSQL Server Timeout Issue with pgAdmin

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin, dbeaver

I am using PostgreSQL 15.4 on Ubuntu 22.04. Initially, I used pgAdmin 4 for managing the database. However, I've been facing an issue where pgAdmin stops responding after some time. This issue seems to be related to a potential timeout caused by the server. It appears that the timeout occurs after around 10 minutes, which is when pgAdmin becomes unresponsive. To resolve this, I need to disconnect from the server and then reconnect, or I have to close pgAdmin and restart it. This has become quite tedious as this happens roughly every 10 minutes (though I'm not entirely sure about the exact interval).

Interestingly, my teammates don't encounter this problem and can use pgAdmin for 4-5 hours straight without any issues. This leads me to believe that there might be something specific to my setup causing this.

In an attempt to troubleshoot, I even uninstalled the pgAdmin desktop version and tried using the web version, but the issue persisted – the interface kept endlessly reloading. I then tried using a different administration tool, like DBeaver, but unfortunately encountered the same problem again.

Has anyone faced a similar issue with PostgreSQL server timeouts causing problems with database management tools? Is there a solution or a way to diagnose and fix this problem? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions.

**TL;DR**
I'm using PostgreSQL 15.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 with pgAdmin 4 for database management. However, I'm encountering an issue where both pgAdmin (desktop and web versions) and DBeaver freeze after around 10 minutes of usage, seemingly due to a server timeout. Unlike me, my teammates can work for hours without a problem.

I've tried reinstalling, switching to different tools, and using both pgAdmin versions. But the problem persists. Any ideas on diagnosing and resolving this timeout-related freezing issue?

### Edit:

pgAdmin4 logs
I want to share these logs on stackoverflow, check for any sensitive information

### pgAdmin Runtime Environment

Python Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3"
Runtime Config File: "/home/rhythmflow/.config/pgadmin/runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py"
Webapp Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 -s /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
Environment:

- GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS: JS ERROR;JS LOG
- USER: rhythmflow
- XDG_SESSION_TYPE: wayland
- SHLVL: 0
- HOME: /home/rhythmflow
- DESKTOP_SESSION: ubuntu
- GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE: /usr/share/applications/pgadmin4.desktop
- GTK_MODULES: gail:atk-bridge
- GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE: ubuntu
- HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
- MANAGERPID: 2002
- SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID: 2221
- DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
- GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID: 17739
- IM_CONFIG_PHASE: 1
- INFOPATH: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:
- WAYLAND_DISPLAY: wayland-0
- LOGNAME: rhythmflow
- _: /usr/bin/gnome-session
- JOURNAL_STREAM: 8:31556
- XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
- USERNAME: rhythmflow
- GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID: this-is-deprecated
- PATH: /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v16.16.0-linux-x64/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/rhythmflow/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
- HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar
- SESSION_MANAGER: local/rhythmflow-Latitude-3400:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2202,unix/rhythmflow-Latitude-3400:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2202
- INVOCATION_ID: 7316dba9e15c4515b8e967532935e244
- XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: /run/user/1000
- XDG_MENU_PREFIX: gnome-
- GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY: :1
- DISPLAY: :0
- LANG: en_IN
- XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: ubuntu:GNOME
- XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP: ubuntu
- XMODIFIERS: @im=ibus
- XAUTHORITY: /run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.0E8291
- SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER: gnome-keyring
- SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
- SHELL: /bin/bash
- QT_ACCESSIBILITY: 1
- GDMSESSION: ubuntu
- GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT: stderr
- QT_IM_MODULE: ibus
- PWD: /home/rhythmflow
- XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
- XDG_CONFIG_DIRS: /etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
- HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
- MANPATH: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:
- GDK_BACKEND: x11
- NO_AT_BRIDGE: 1
- PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF

---

Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.005 Sec
2023-08-21 12:27:43,525: WARNING    werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.
2023-08-21 12:27:43,525: WARNING    werkzeug:   Werkzeug appears to be used in a production deployment. Consider switching to a production web server instead.

- Serving Flask app 'pgadmin'
- Debug mode: off

Total time taken to ping pgAdmin4 server: 3.243 Sec
Total launch time of pgAdmin4: 3.293 Sec
Application Server URL:

Comment: A timeout would surely be logged.  What is in the db logs?